# Where and How to properly use enablePersistence() method from Firebase, for offline use of the web app?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps, offline

I made a simple web app with Vue.js and Firestore. I want to cache the web app and display the page even with no internet connection. I am not getting the desired results when I use the  enablePersistence() method  in the firebase configuration file in my Vue project built with PWA template. I tried to use that method in the lifecycle methods within the app components, still not getting the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring it in your Firebase configuration file as follows should do the trick:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

var config = {
    apiKey: ....,
    authDomain: ....,
    //.....
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

db.enablePersistence();

export { db, auth };
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying.  I am using it just like you wrote here. It looks like caching is done. But now I am having trouble fetching the cached data when I am offline. Can you provide  a link to some tutorial or article related to that?

Comment: You should fetch the data exactly the same way as for online mode: actually there is nothing to change/add to your code, the offline mode is fully managed by the SDK. **However**, in my experience, it can take **much longer** to query (cached) collections when being offline...

Comment: Note that enablePersistence returns a promise that resolves only after persistence is actually enabled. The client code should check that before making any requests. It should also check it for errors to know if persistence is actually available (it won't be in all circumstances).

Comment: how to do it with firebase 10? `TS2339: Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'typeof import(<path>)'.`